# Proving if $x<y$ then $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

I am stuck on this homework problem!

Prove that if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $0<x<y$ , then $\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{y}$.

This is in a chapter involving the least upper bound axiom and the Archimedean Principle, but I cannot figure how to use either of those to prove this!  Any help would be most appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Is there a part missing to the question?

Comment: oops, I think you want to clarify your problem statement in your post...if $x, y > 0?$...and what is it to prove?

Comment: Have you tried proving the contrapositive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hint : $ y-x=(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})$ Now look at the signs..

Comment: This idea popped into my mind immediately after reading the question.

Comment: This was really beautiful

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $0 < a < b$, multiplying by a gives us, $0 < \color{brown}{a^2 < ab}$.
Similarly, multiplying by $b$ gives $0 < \color{green}{ab < b^2}$ so $ab < b^2$. So from the brown and green, we have $0 < a < b \Leftrightarrow 0 < a^2 < b^2$.

Notice that your result is a corollary of this, let $x = a^2$ and $y = b^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: write it in contrapositive form - if $\sqrt{x}\geq \sqrt{y}$, then $x\geq y$ (assuming $x,y>0$).